# Multiple line text save to file with Makefile

Tags: makefile, apache2, gnu-make

I want to save multiple line text to a file with GNU Make(Makefile). But it give me error. I want to make a virtual host configuration file with this script. $$dir will be the name given by user.Help me,plz.

```
define info =
        echo <VirtualHost *:80>
        echo    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        echo    ServerName  $$dir.io
         echo    ServerAlias www.$$dir.io
         echo    DocumentRoot /var/www/$$dir/public_html
         echo    <Directory /var/www/$$dir/public_html/>
         echo        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         echo        AllowOverride All
         echo        Order allow,deny
         echo        allow from all
         echo    </Directory>
         echo </VirtualHost>
      endef

  echo $$info > /etc/apache2/sites-avaliable/$$dir.; \
  echo "Done"
```

Answer (score 1):

This example is so broken it makes me wonder if you even tried to make this work, or if you just typed a "best guess" directly into a StackOverflow question.

```
info = \
    echo '<VirtualHost *:80>'; \
    echo '   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost'; \
    echo '   ServerName  $$dir.io'; \
    echo '   ServerAlias www.$$dir.io'; \
    echo '   DocumentRoot /var/www/$$dir/public_html'; \
    echo '   <Directory /var/www/$$dir/public_html/>'; \
    echo '       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews'; \
    echo '       AllowOverride All'; \
    echo '       Order allow,deny'; \
    echo '       allow from all'; \
    echo '   </Directory>'; \
    echo '</VirtualHost>';

all:
        ( $(info) ) > /etc/apache2/sites-avaliable/$(dir); \
        echo "Done"
```

You don't specify exactly what "given by the user" means (on the make command line?  In the environment?  elsewhere in the makefile?).

Comment: I want to get the host name from user via cli. Thanks, for your answer.It is just a piece or code. My script file is too long for other feature. So I posted only the one what I got problem.